MDX is not returning result
I have a mdx query which i taking forever to run i am new to MDX and not sure what is wrong with this query and why results are not coming ?
Here is my query
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Resource].[Manager Name].[All]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS  FROM [PortMart] WHERE ([Resource OBS - Current].[Resource OBS Level3].&[Ryan O'Neill],[Resource OBS - Current].[Resource OBS Level4].[All],[Resource].[Active Status].&[Active],[Resource].[Open for Time Entry].&[Not Open],[Resource].[Resource Type].&[Employee]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, LANGUAGE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FONT_FLAGS
